# ¿Cómo alinear horizontalmente divs que son generados por un while?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, div

Estoy desarrollando un sitio en el cual deseo mostrar datos que recibo de la base de datos, pero a la hora de ordenar los divs con su respectivo contenido dentro, me encuentro con que los divs no se generan horizontalmente automáticamente, si no que un div debajo del otro, agradecería que me ayudaran con el código o que me den pistas para poder seguir avanzando, les agradezco mucho. En definitiva necesito que el div "seccion" se repita horizontalmente cada vez que el while actúe siempre dentro del div padre que seria "marcoGrande". Adjunto código e imágenes.

```
    <div id="marcoGrande">

<?php
include("paginas/listarProductos.php");
if($resultado){     
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_array()){
    $nombre = $row['nombre'];
    $precio = $row['precio'];
 ?>
    <div id="seccion">
 <img id="imagenArticulo" src="imagenes/imagenesArticulos/<?php echo 
  $row['imagen']; ?>"/><?php

        ?><div id="nombreArticulo"> <?php
     echo $nombre;


    ?>     </div>   <?php


            ?>      <div id="precioArticulo">   <?php
    echo "$".$precio;?>
                    </div>

     <img id="logoPrecio" src="imagenes/logoPrecio.png">

     <?php


    }

    }


   ?>
    </div>

    </div>


CSS

  #seccion{

  border:solid #eebbac;
  margin-left:10px;
  width:300px;
  height:310px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:white;
  padding-right:5px;


  }

#marcoGrande{

border:#fbd4c9;
border-style:dotted;

margin-top:15px;
margin-left:260px;
margin-right:10px;
border-radius:40px;
height:auto;
padding-bottom:40px;
width:auto;

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí adjunto imágen de como se encuentran ahora, yo lo que necesito es que cada una se muestre continuadamente al costado, no debajo como está actualmente.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código CSS que estás usando. Te recomiendo usar `flex` y que leas este [tutorial](https://www.yunbitsoftware.com/blog/2017/03/30/flexbox-css3-tutorial-descripcion-ejemplos-html/) para que elijas la opción que mejor se adapte a tu diseño.

Comment: Muchas gracias, añadí el css al final porque no supe separarlo en dos secciones, investigaré lo que me recomendaste, nuevamente gracias.

Comment: Otra opción es usar bootstrap, aunque así a bote pronto, lo más rápido que se me ocurre sin tener que trabajar mucho es poner un float: left a los divs

Comment: Gracias por responder, probé usar bootstrap pero no supe aplicarlo bien, quizás necesite dedicarle un poco mas de tiempo. Por otro lado, probe lo del float:left en el div (que es uno solo que se genera dinamicamente), y queda de la misma forma. Gracias por responder nuevamente.

Comment: No sé como decirte esto pero creo que te amo jajaj. Me solucionaron el problema, muchisimas gracias a todos. Soy nuevo en la plataforma, ¿debería cambiar el título y ponerlo como solucionado?

Comment: Aunque ya no aplica, para que lo sepas, si haces float: left, también tienes que hacer un width: algo (por ejemplo, 100px o 300px) de lo contrario puede que valga 100% y por tanto, no se realiza el float: left

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado! Gracias a sugerencias de aquí logré hacer que las imágenes se alineen correctamente, la solución es en el div padre colocar el display:flex; adjunto como quedaría un ejemplo de código más abajo. Ahora tengo otro problema, al seguir agregando divs, se siguen alineando horizontalmente, es decir, el siguiente no baja a otra línea, continúa alineado con el resto. Estuve pensando en cómo poder hacer que el div padre limite el espacio y que el próximo div baje automáticamente.

Adjunto código de la solución principal (solo hay que cambiar el css):

```
#seccion{

 border:solid #eebbac;
 margin-left:10px;
 width:300px;
 height:310px;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:white;
 padding-right:5px;

 }

 #marcoGrande{

 border:#fbd4c9;
 border-style:dotted;
 margin-top:15px;
 margin-left:260px;
 margin-right:10px;
 border-radius:40px;
 height:auto;
 padding-bottom:40px;
 width:100%;
 display:flex;

 }
```

Les agradezco si me pueden ayudar con el nuevo inconveniente. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo edito, de igual manera sigue sin hacer el "salto de linea".

Comment: Perfecto! Puse esa propiedad y el width en 900px y funciona exactamente como pensaba. Ahora me pregunto que tan responsive es, ya que estoy definiendo el width con pixeles, antes estaba al 100% pero no se porque los elementos sobrepasaban los limites del div padre.

Comment: Pruebo y cuando lo consiga publico la respuesta, infinitas gracias, no sabía que iba a ser tan rápida la respuesta.

Comment: para que te sea full responsive define el tamaño máximo que pueda tener tu `div` con `max-width` y define el `width` como `100%` de esta manera si el tamaño del dispositivo es menor al de tu div entonces se ajustara a la pantalla pero si es mayor entonces tomara el valor máximo.